# tensorflow softmax_cross_entropy code

Tags: tensorflow, softmax, cross-entropy

Since the source code of `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` in `gen_nn_ops` is hidden, could anyone perhaps explain me how tensorflow compute the cross entropy after Softmax. I mean, after softmax it might output 0 because of precision which will give rise to a NaN problem with cross entropy. Did tensorflow use clip method when softmax to bound the output of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The implementation of `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` further goes to native C++ code, [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.3/tensorflow/compiler/tf2xla/kernels/softmax_op.cc#L81) is XLA implementation. Logits are not bound and `0` is possible when one of the logits is much bigger than others. Example:

```
>>> session.run(tf.nn.softmax([10.0, 50.0, 100.0, 200.0]))
array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.], dtype=float32)
```

If you wish, you can clip the logits just before the softmax, but it's not recommended, because it kills the gradient when the output is large. A better option is to use [batch normalization](https://kratzert.github.io/2016/02/12/understanding-the-gradient-flow-through-the-batch-normalization-layer.html) to make the activations more like normally distributed.